# android date picker not working in api 19 while it works in lollipop

Tags: datepicker, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat

I have used `DatePickerDialog` to show dialog which is working in Lollipop mobiles but not working in android api 19. There is also problem in android google maps. Maps are visible in lollipop but not shows black screen in kitkat.

Here the code:

```
final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        date.setText(Integer.toString(dayOfMonth));
        month.setText(Integer.toString(monthOfYear));
        yearr.setText(Integer.toString(year));
        //SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        //chosenDate=simpleDateFormat.parse(Integer.toString(dayOfMonth)+"/"+Integer.toString(monthOfYear)+"/"+Integer.toString(year));
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,monthOfYear);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        chosenDate=cal.getTime();
        for(int i=0;i<7;i++) {
            Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
            c.set(year,monthOfYear,dayOfMonth,10+i*2,0,0);
            times[i]=new Date();
            times[i] = c.getTime();
        }
    }
};
final TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.et_time);
datepicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        time.setText("");
        DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(BookingService.this, datePickerListener,
                cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        datePicker.setCancelable(false);
        datePicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(new Date().getTime());
        Dialog dialog=datePicker;
        dialog.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: The issue is real, a DatePicker in API level 19 shows both, a calender and a spinner as `android:datePickerMode` is not used under API level 21